# When Performing .take() function on the rdd I am getting the ouput in the array form . But when I am performing .getClass() it is showing string

Tags: apache-spark

When I am performing `.take()` on the base_rdd, the output is an Array:

[image]

When I am performing `.getClass()`, I am getting string as a return type:

[image]

My question is how to get array as return type?

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String;` means Java array (of Strings). That is the return type of `take(n)`.

Comment: @mazaneicha , class [Ljava.lang.String and class java.lang.String . Are these two different?

Comment: Yes, `[L` is the notation meaning "array of some objects (non-primitives)".